# openvpn server doesn't NAT the incoming traffic

Tags: openvpn

It's couple of days that I'm having hard time figuring out what's wrong with openVPN. Few days ago, I installed and configured openVPN on a Debian server and also on my Ubuntu client. I am facing a weird behavior: OpenVPN server NATs the incoming traffic whenever it wants, but not always!

It looks that the ***iptables*** rules on the Debian server get deleted at some specified time every day (I'm not sure though), because **the next day if I re-enter the iptable rules (for NAT & DNS queries forwarding) like following,**

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun+ -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 8.8.8.8
```

**and force-reload openvpn daemon and restart openvpn (at both ends), the traffic gets routed as it should.** I've saved iptables rules in the file */etc/iptables.conf* and I reload it at boot (*/etc/rc.local*), but nevertheless the problem still persists. Here is the content of my ***/etc/iptables.conf***:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Tue Apr 15 13:50:46 2014
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [166249:16762540]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [3659:1318578]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [165776:17724102]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Apr 15 13:50:46 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Tue Apr 15 13:50:46 2014
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [169911:18081298]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [165776:17724102]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Apr 15 13:50:46 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Tue Apr 15 13:50:46 2014
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [42:2524]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1:40]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [24:1504]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [24:1504]
-A PREROUTING -i tun+ -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 8.8.8.8
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Apr 15 13:50:46 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Tue Apr 15 13:50:46 2014
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [169911:18081298]
:INPUT ACCEPT [166249:16762540]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [3659:1318578]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [165776:17724102]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [169435:19042680]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Apr 15 13:50:46 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Tue Apr 15 13:50:46 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [166249:16762540]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [3659:1318578]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [165776:17724102]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Apr 15 13:50:46 2014
```

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446003/route-traffic-throught-openvpn) I've posted my config files. The differences in my working client.conf & server.conf with those in that post are as follows:

```
# client.conf

user nobody
group nogroup    
redirect-gateway def1 #bypass-dns bypass-dhcp
```

server:

```
# server.conf

; duplicate-cn #not needed, commented out    
user nobody
group nogroup
```

I'll be deeply grateful if you save me from this chaos!

Comment: By the way, when I run iptables --list, it shows an empty list. weird, isn't it?